# null values returning from gson.fromJson

Tags: java, json

I have some values in my object are returning by value null when converting from json to object and some others doesn't,i can't figure out why is that happening
here's my code to convert

```
OriginalMovie originalMovie = gson.fromJson(jsonString, OriginalMovie.class);
```

here's my json

```
 {"page":1,
"results":[{"adult":false,
"backdrop_path":"/o4I5sHdjzs29hBWzHtS2MKD3JsM.jpg",
"genre_ids":[878,28,53,12],
"id":87101,"original_language":"en",
"original_title":"Terminator Genisys",
"overview":"The year is 2029. John Connor, leader of the resistance continues the war against the machines.",
"release_date":"2015-07-01",
"poster_path":"/5JU9ytZJyR3zmClGmVm9q4Geqbd.jpg",
"popularity":54.970301,
"title":"Terminator Genisys","video":false,
"vote_average":6.4,
"vote_count":197}],
"total_pages":11666,"total_results":233312}
```

and here's my base class (contains results)

```
package MovieReviewHelper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class OriginalMovie 
{

    private long page;
    private List<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
    private long totalPages;
    private long totalResults;
    public long getPage() 
    {
        return page;
    }
    public void setPage(long page)
    {
        this.page = page;
    }
    public List<Result> getResults()
    {
        return results;
    }
    public void setResults(List<Result> results)
    {
        this.results = results;
    }
    public long getTotalPages() {
        return totalPages;
    }
    public void setTotalPages(long totalPages) 
    {
        this.totalPages = totalPages;
    }
    public long getTotalResults()
    {
        return totalResults;
    }
    public void setTotalResults(long totalResults)
    {
        this.totalResults = totalResults;
    }

}
```

and here's my other class

```
package MovieReviewHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Result {

    private boolean adult;
    private String backdropPath;
    private List<Long> genreIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
    private long id;
    private String originalLanguage;
    private String originalTitle;
    private String overview;
    private String releaseDate;
    private String posterPath;
    private double popularity;
    private String title;
    private boolean video;
    private double voteAverage;
    private long voteCount;
    public boolean isAdult()
    {
        return adult;
    }
    public void setAdult(boolean adult)
    {
        this.adult = adult;
    }
    public String getBackdropPath() 
    {
        return backdropPath;
    }
    public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) 
    {
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
    }
    public List<Long> getGenreIds() 
    {
        return genreIds;
    }
    public void setGenreIds(List<Long> genreIds)
    {
        this.genreIds = genreIds;
    }
    public long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getOriginalLanguage() 
    {
        return originalLanguage;
    }
    public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage)
    {
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
    }
    public String getOriginalTitle() 
    {
        return originalTitle;
    }
    public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) 
    {
        this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
    }
    public String getOverview()
    {
        return overview;
    }
    public void setOverview(String overview)
    {
        this.overview = overview;
    }
    public String getReleaseDate() 
    {
        return releaseDate;
    }
    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) 
    {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }
    public String getPosterPath() 
    {
        return posterPath;
    }
    public void setPosterPath(String posterPath)
    {
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
    }
    public double getPopularity()
    {
        return popularity;
    }
    public void setPopularity(double popularity)
    {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }
    public String getTitle() 
    {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public boolean isVideo() 
    {
        return video;
    }
    public void setVideo(boolean video)
    {
        this.video = video;
    }
    public double getVoteAverage() 
    {
        return voteAverage;
    }
    public void setVoteAverage(double voteAverage)
    {
        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
    }
    public long getVoteCount()
    {
        return voteCount;
    }
    public void setVoteCount(long voteCount) 
    {
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    }


}
```

Comment: Which ones are returned as null?

Comment: all except 4 values (popularity,title,id,overview)

Comment: that must be all with underscores in the name?

Comment: ops, my fault , thx @Sandeep

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Json and Class variables should have the same name.
`backdrop_path` in Json and `backdropPath` in class would not work

Answer (score 0):

Incase this helps for someone like me who spent half a day in trying to figure out a similar issue with gson.fromJson() returning object with null values, but when using @JsonProperty with an underscore in name and using Lombok in the model class.

My model class had a property like below and am using Lombok @Data for class

```
@JsonProperty(value="dsv_id")
private String dsvId;
```

So in my Json file I was using

```
"dsv_id"="123456"
```

Which was causing null value. The way I resolved it was changing the Json to have below ie.without the underscore. That fixed the problem for me.

```
"dsvId = "123456"
```